# What does `{ { (exit 1); exit 1; }; }` mean?

Tags: shell, shell-script, configure

I quoted the next code snippet from `config.status` generated by `configure`.

```
if test ! -f "$as_myself"; then
{ { echo "$as_me:$LINENO: error: cannot find myself; rerun with an absolute path" >&5
echo "$as_me: error: cannot find myself; rerun with an absolute path" >&2;}
{ (exit 1); exit 1; }; }
fi
```

In the code snippet, what does `{ (exit 1); exit 1; };` do? What's the purpose of only doing `exit` in a subshell?

Answer (score 35):

Executing `(exit 1);` is the simplest way of triggering an `ERR` trap. It will also trigger immediate exit if `set -e` is in effect. (Triggering the error condition requires a command to fail; `exit` with a failure value in a subshell causes the subshell to fail.)

`exit 1;` will do neither of those things.

So `{(exit 1); exit 1;}` can be used to first produce the `ERR` trap, which might do something useful for debugging purposes, and then terminate the script with an error indication.

But that's not what is going on in `autoconf` files. `autoconf` scripts rely on the `EXIT` trap in order to clean up temporary files created during the run. Most shells, including `bash` will set the status from the value provided in the `exit` command before calling the `EXIT` trap. That could allow the `EXIT` trap to detect whether it was invoked from an error or from normal termination, and it also allows it to ensure that the exit status is correctly set at the end of the trap operation.

However, apparently some shells do not co-operate. Here's a quote from the [`autoconf` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.64/html_node/Limitations-of-Builtins.html):

> Some shell scripts, such as those generated by `autoconf`, use a trap to clean up before exiting. If the last shell command exited with nonzero status, the trap also exits with nonzero status so that the invoker can tell that an error occurred.
>
> Unfortunately, in some shells, such as Solaris `/bin/sh`, an exit trap ignores the exit command's argument. In these shells, a trap cannot determine whether it was invoked by plain exit or by exit 1. Instead of calling exit directly, use the `AC_MSG_ERROR` macro that has a workaround for this problem.

The workaround is to make sure that `$?` has the exit status *before* the `exit` command is executed, so that it will definitely have that value when the `EXIT` trap is executed. And, indeed, it is the `AC_MSG_ERROR` macro which inserts that curious code, complete with redundant braces.

Comment: Why not just execute `false` instead of `(exit 1)`?

Comment: @Ruslan: Two problems. (1) Most important: `false` doesn't let you set the status code and there is no guarantee as to what non-zero status it returns. (2) `false` is not usually a builtin, so it requires a child process; in contrast, most shells can avoid spawning a child to handle `(exit 1)`.

Answer (score 8):

There is no purpose for this as far as I can see, there is nothing that can be achieved directly by starting a subshell and then immediately exiting.

Things like this are most likely a side effect of automatically generating code - in some cases there may be other commands executed in the subshell where having the `exit 1` makes sense. Ultimately there is a good chance that the generation code is somehow simplified by allowing it to insert some statements that don't have any function in some cases rather and generating 'clean code' every single time is more complex. Either that or the code which generated the above is just poorly written :)

The liberal use of `{...}` is another example of this, most of them are redundant, but it is easier to write code that inserts them in every case (maybe in some you want to redirect the output/input of the block) rather than to distinguish the ones where they are not needed and omit them.

Comment: It does have a purpose. See @rici's answer.

Answer (score 1):

`(exit 1)` is a simple, probably the most simple way to get a certain exit code (in the special case of 1 there are easier ways, of course). But that is not the reason in this case as the exit code is not examined.

The purpose of putting `exit` in a subshell may be to not exit the script (though using exit for the generation of a certain exit code).